# Show WooCommerce short description/excerpt but not in mega menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I have code in my child theme functions.php that shows the WooCommerce product short description or excerpt on category pages, but I have products in my 'mega' menu and the short description is also showing there. I can't think of a way to prevent this other than hiding the elements via CSS, but this is an imperfect solution and I'd be much happier if the short description was only being output once, where I need it.

```
function add_short_description_in_product_categories() {
  if( is_product_category() ) {
    global $product;

    echo '<div itemprop="description">' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_short_description() ) . '</div>';
  }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_short_description_in_product_categories', 5);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` hook for this, then I don't see how that could affect your mega menu - unless that is somehow dynamically created on the client side?

Comment: It's been added to the mega menu using the [product id="xxx"] shortcode so it's basically pulling everything through you'd expect to see in the category view, and there are no parameters available to use in the shortcode to determine what's output.

Comment: You could create your own little shortcode, that outputs just the product info you need within the menu, and then use that in there.

Comment: That's a good shout, thanks - I'm pulling something together and will answer my own question once I've got it working.